# How to check if iPhone is connected with 360 degree camera?

Tags: ios, swift, 360-degrees, theta360

I am using Ricoh-Theta camera which is built upon **Open Spherical Camera API**. It is the protocol used in a 360-degree camera. I am trying to understand how can I check if that camera is connected with device or not?

The camera creates wifi-hotspot that mobile uses. the camera acts as an HTTP server. the app sends HTTP request to server and server gives back a response. I am trying to understand that if I have to check the connectivity between my device and camera, Do I need to fire API to camera server?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option captureStatus that can give back information on "idle", "shooting", and more.

https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/reference/options

I have cross-posted to the theta360.guide developer community to see if there is more information available.

https://community.theta360.guide/t/how-to-check-if-iphone-is-connected-with-360-degree-camera/4419

Comment: Thanks, @Jesse. I don't think with the capture status command you can actually get the information which is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In access point mode, the IP address is 192.168.1.1.  You can try and ping that.  The problem is that if you're connected to a router on that subnet, then you'll get a response. You can get a response from info.
https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/v2.1/api_reference/protocols/info.html

or state

https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/v2.1/api_reference/protocols/state.html

Why are you unable to send an HTTP request?